# Summation of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\frac12\ln2+\frac1{2^2}\ln2^2+\frac1{2^3}\ln2^3+\cdots+\frac1{2^m}\ln2^m+\cdots$$
The answer says this series should sum to 4. Could someone please help how to get the correct result? I am confused which formulas to use and how.

Comment: Is that $\log(2^m)$ or $(\log 2)^m$?

Comment: Use geometric series!

Comment: It's log(2^m), only the two goes to the power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m$th term is $\frac 1{2^m}\ln2^m=(\ln 2){\frac m{2^m}}$

$$\sum_{1\le r<\infty} \ln 2^{\frac r{2^r}}=(\ln2){\sum_{1\le r<\infty}\frac m{2^m}}$$

Let $S={\sum_{1\le r<\infty}\frac m{2^m}}=\frac 12+\frac 2{2^2}+\frac 3{2^3}+\cdots$ (This is a [Arithmetico-geometric series](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Arithmetico-geometric_series))

So, dividing either sides by $2,\frac S 2=\frac 1{2^2}+\frac 2{2^3}+\frac 3{2^4}+\cdots$

On subtraction, $\frac S 2=\frac 12+\frac 1{2^2}+\frac 1{2^3}+\cdots$

$\frac S 2=\frac {\frac 12}{1-\frac 12}$ (Using infinite geometric Progression with common ratio$=\frac 12<1$)

So, $S=2$

$$\sum_{1\le r<\infty} \ln 2^{\frac r{2^r}}=(\ln2){\sum_{1\le r<\infty}\frac m{2^m}}=2\ln2=\ln 4$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $\ln 2^m=m\ln 2$.
Then we see that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{2^k}\ln 2^k = \ln2\cdot\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac k{2^k}$$
Next observe that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac k{2^k}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac12\frac {k-1}{2^{k-1}}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^k}=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac k{2^k}+1.$$
Hence (once you agree that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac k{2^k}$ converges)
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{2^k}\ln 2^k=2\ln2.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}nx^n=x/(1-x)^2$ for every $|x|\lt1$. (And the answer is not $4$.)